# Talend tSendMail AWS SES TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 deprecation error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tls1.2, talend, amazon-ses

Environment:-
Talend 7.0.1.20180411_1414
Java 1.8.0_171
AWS Java SDK 1.11.269

When I execute the project after building it.
I see following error:
***com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Access denied: Amazon SES no longer supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. You must update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb. For further assistance, contact AWS support***

I have tried updating the mail library in talend as mentioned in (this talend community post)(https://community.talend.com/s/article/Issue-with-tSendMail-and-TLS-version-ElVmA?language=en_US) .
But it doesn't fix the issue.

I can update Java but I learned that this installed version already has tls1.2 support.
I can also update the aws java sdk, but I do not know if this error is related to that.
I cannot update talend because the project will need migration.

Please keep in mind I am new to talend and this project is very old, we are migrating it but it must be kept online for now.

Please help me understand what component I need to update/upgrade to make this error go away. It affects our alert system.

Many thanks.